# What tag should I use for these questions about political organization?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently posted somequestions about political organizations:

- [In U.S. local politics, what is the relationship between a campaign and a party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30840/in-u-s-local-politics-what-is-the-relationship-between-a-campaign-and-a-party)
- [Where do local political parties get their revenues?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30895/where-do-local-political-parties-in-the-united-states-get-their-revenues)
- [How do I hire a campaign manager?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30949/how-do-i-hire-a-campaign-manager)

My intent was to ask questions about the internal business of political organizations people with boots-on-the-ground experience could answer.

However, I'm not sure how to tag these. I created the [party-operations](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/party-operations) tag with the idea that it would encapsulate questions about the operations of political organizations, but I basically made that term up.

Is there a better tag for these questions?

Answer (score -1):

Tags are intended to connect experts with meaningful questions. The question to ask when adding a tag is "can you be an expert in this?"

In this case, can you be an expert on "parties" but *not* be an expert on "party operations"? Probably not.

Therefore, I would say that adding tags like these is redundant.

Comment: I think you can. Many political scientists have excellent knowledge of political parties, without being knowledgeable in their internal workings. Sort of the difference between an economist and a department manager. So the tag helps differentiate between those different fields of expertise.